# 'dict' object is not callable error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

ordered_satisfaction = ['Very Unhappy', 'Unhappy', 'Neutral', 'Happy', 'Very Happy']

df = pd.DataFrame({'satisfaction': ['Mad', 'Happy', 'Unhappy', 'Neutral']})

df.satisfaction = df.satisfaction.astype('category', ordered=True, categories=ordered_satisfaction).cat.codes

print df
```

I get a `'dict' object is not callable` error for the above code. I am using python 2 (Anaconda).

Comment: What is your Pandas version?

Comment: pandas version is 0.18.1.

Comment: no, the entirety of my code is as given above

Comment: I tested it on Anaconda 2 (Pandas 0.18.1) - it works just fine for me

Comment: hmm, that's strange. I am using jupyter notebook in internet explorer.

Comment: Ok, so getting rid of the spaces for the following piece of code solved the issue: ordered = True and categories = ordered_satisfaction. Also got rid of the parentheses for the print call

Comment: If you solved your issue please post an answer or remove the question, but *don't* edit the question to have the working code.